# java rectangle not spawning in the correct position

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am attempting to made a Java game, when I had a new idea. I am attempting to make `rectangle` & `rectangle2` to be randomly placed along the screen at different sizes

> Obstacle class

```
public Obstacle(int rectHeight, int color ,  int startX, int startY, int playerGap) {
    this.color = color;
    rectangle = new Rect(0, startY , startX , startY + rectHeight);
    rectangle2 = new Rect(startX + playerGap, startY , Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH , startY + rectHeight);

}
```

> ObstacleManager class

```
private void populateObstacles(){
    int currY = -5*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/4;
    while (currY < 0){
        int xStart = (int)(Math.random() *(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH - playerGap));
        obstacles.add(new Obstacle(obstacleHeight,color, xStart  , currY, playerGap));
        currY += obstacleHeight + obstacleGap;
    }
}
```

What i'm trying to do is have every rectangle be 100px and each of them to spawn at different locations. So `rectangle` would come in every 200px and `rectangle2` comes in every 400px

> This is what im getting

[image]

> What I want

[image]
(I made this in paint, but you should get the idea)

Thank you

Comment: well, when i try to make each rectangle 100px, it seems to just move it to the right which doesn't make since cause that's not the part i'm coding

Comment: ok sorry it took so long, I made a picture in paint so it should give you the idea of what im looking for

Comment: try resizing your code. It looks like the rectangles might just being displayed larger than you intend.

Comment: resizing? you mean the height of them?